# Ctypes array of struct in struct. How can I access indexes other than 0?

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I can access first index perfectly fine. However, other indexes do not give me anything. They are blank.

Here is my c code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_UUID (256)
#define MAX_DEVICES_PER_NODE (16)

typedef struct uuid_s{
    char uuid[MAX_LENGTH_UUID];
}uuid_t;

typedef struct device_list_s{
    unsigned num_devices;
    uuid_t dev_list[MAX_DEVICES_PER_NODE];
}device_list_t;

int is04_get_device_lists(device_list_t *devl)
{
    devl->num_devices = 2;
    strcpy(devl->dev_list[0].uuid, "HEHEHEHEHE");
    strcpy(devl->dev_list[1].uuid, "NONONONONO");
    return 4;
}

int is04_pass_device_lists(device_list_t *dev_list)
{
    printf("Num Devices: %d\n", dev_list->num_devices);
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < dev_list->num_devices; i++)
    {
        printf("Device %d: %s\n", i, dev_list->dev_list[i].uuid);
    }
}
```

Here is my python code.

```
from ctypes import *

MAX_LENGTH_UUID = 256
MAX_DEVICES_PER_NODE = 16

class uuid_t(Structure):
    pass
uuid_t._fields_ = [("uuid", c_char*MAX_LENGTH_UUID)]

class device_list_t(Structure):
    pass
device_list_t._fields_ = [("num_devices", c_uint),
                          ("dev_list", uuid_t*MAX_DEVICES_PER_NODE)]

def main():
    folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    dll_path = os.path.join(folder, "libnmos.so")
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
    print ''
    dev_list = device_list_t()
    print '[GetDeviceList] Returned value: ' + str(dll.is04_get_device_lists(byref(dev_list)))
    print '[GetDeviceList] Total devices: ' + str(dev_list.num_devices)
    print '[GetDeviceList] First Device: ' + dev_list.dev_list[0].uuid
    # print dev_list
    print '[GetDeviceList] Second Device: ' + dev_list.dev_list[1].uuid

    dev_list_2 = device_list_t()
    dev_list_2.num_devices = 2
    dev_list_2.dev_list[0].uuid = "Hello"
    dev_list_2.dev_list[1].uuid = "World"
    dll.is04_pass_device_lists(byref(dev_list_2))

    print '[PassDeviceList] dev_0: ', dev_list_2.dev_list[0].uuid
    print '[PassDeviceList] dev_1: ', dev_list_2.dev_list[1].uuid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output.

```
[GetDeviceList] Returned value: 4
[GetDeviceList] Total devices: 2
[GetDeviceList] First Device: HEHEHEHEHE
[GetDeviceList] Second Device: 
Num Devices: 2
Device 0: Hello
Device 1: 
[PassDeviceList] dev_0:  Hello
[PassDeviceList] dev_1:  World
```

I am unable to access index 1 in c and python.

Edit: Added the c includes.

System info:
Linux bthapa-dev 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bthapa@bthapa-dev:/usr/bin$ which python
/usr/bin/python

bthapa@bthapa-dev:/usr/bin$ ls -al python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 30 22:51 python -> python2.7

Comment: Start by testing the shared library in C to ensure it was built correctly. Also, you should include the headers <string.h> and <stdio.h>.

Comment: I tested the shared library with the c code. It works perfectly fine. If you need the test c code I can update the question with test code.

Comment: I tested your code on 64-bit Linux, and it worked fine. I don't readily see why you're having a problem printing `dev_list->dev_list[1].uuid`.

Comment: Could you share some info about your _OS_, _Python_ version (already got that it's _2.X_ (< 3))...

Comment: Added the system info in description.

Comment: I tested it in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit vm and it works. Not sure why it is not working on my laptop. Thanks for helping. My laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: So it's the __exact__ same code, that works on your _Ubtu14 x64_ VM, but not in your _Ubtu_ (sorry, didn't get the version the _system info_ you added - is it an `uname` output?)

Comment: Yeah it is the uname output. And yeah, the code is exactly same.